# Prevent a user from deleting BigQuery tables

Tags: google-bigquery

We're trying to create a very basic role that allows users to query BigQuery tables, but not delete them.  The custom role we're experimenting with now has the following permissions:

```
- bigquery.jobs.create
- bigquery.jobs.get
- bigquery.jobs.list
- bigquery.jobs.listAll
- bigquery.readsessions.create
- bigquery.routines.get
- bigquery.routines.list
- bigquery.savedqueries.get
- bigquery.savedqueries.list
- bigquery.tables.export
- bigquery.tables.getData
- bigquery.tables.list
- bigquery.transfers.get
- resourcemanager.projects.get
```

We're only focusing on delete at this time, so the permissions list is a work in progress.  There is only one custom role assigned to our test user with the above permissions.  However, the user can delete tables from our BigQuery dataset.  Any idea on the correct combinations of permissions to achieve our objective.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your user deleting the table? Is it via a Client library? Is it via the UI?

Comment: via the BigQUery UI

Answer (score 2):

You have listed 14 permissions and seem to be making an assumption these permissions allow BQ table deletion.

This assumption looks odd (because clearly the permission `bigquery.tables.delete` is not on the list) and in fact is incorrect. Which means the GCP IAM identity (a user or a service account) assigned the role comprised of these 14 permissions will be unable to delete BQ tables. This in turn means the identity you are testing with is assigned additional role(s) and/or permission(s) that are not accounted for.

To prove the assumption is incorrect open [BQ Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery) as a project administrator and click on the Cloud Shell icon to start Cloud Shell VM. Then execute the following commands at the command prompt replacing `<project-name>`:

```
# Prove the current user is BQ admin by creating 'ds_test1' dataset,
# 'tbl_test1' table, then deleting and recreating the table
bq mk ds_test1
bq mk -t ds_test1.tbl_test1
bq rm -f -t ds_test1.tbl_test1
bq mk -t ds_test1.tbl_test1

# Create role `role_test1`
gcloud iam roles create role_test1 --project <project-name> --title "Role role_test1" --description "My custom role role_test1" --permissions bigquery.jobs.create,bigquery.jobs.get,bigquery.jobs.list,bigquery.jobs.listAll,bigquery.readsessions.create,bigquery.routines.get,bigquery.routines.list,bigquery.savedqueries.get,bigquery.saved
queries.list,bigquery.tables.export,bigquery.tables.getData,bigquery.tables.list,bigquery.transfers.get,resourcemanager.projects.get --stage GA

# Create service account 'sa-test1'
# It is a good security practice to dispose of it when testing is finished
gcloud iam service-accounts create sa-test1 --display-name "sa-test1" --description "Test SA sa-test1, delete it when not needed anymore" --project <project-name>

# Grant the role (and its permissions) to the service account
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project-name> --member=serviceAccount:sa-test1@<project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role projects/<project-name>/roles/role_test1

# Save the credential of the service account (including the security sensitive
# private key) to a disk file
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ~/key-sa-test1.json --iam-account sa-test1@<project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# Impersonate the service account. This replaces the current permissions with
# that of the service account
gcloud auth activate-service-account sa-test1@<project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=./key-sa-test1.json

# Confirm the ability to list tables
bq ls ds_test1

# Confirm inability to delete tables
# The command fails with error: BigQuery error in rm operation: Access Denied: Table <project-name>:ds_test1.tbl_test1: User does not have bigquery.tables.delete permission for table <project-name>:ds_test1.tbl_test1.
bq rm -f -t ds_test1.tbl_test1

# Close SSH connection to the VM and logoff
exit
```

To see the roles granted to the service account 'sa-test1' created above open Cloud Shell and execute:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <project-name> --flatten="bindings[].members" --filter="bindings.members:serviceAccount:sa-test1@<project-name>.
iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

It should list our role `projects/<project-name>/roles/role_test1`.
To see the roles granted to the user who can delete tables execute:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <project-name> --flatten="bindings[].members" --filter="bindings.members:user:<email-of-the-user>"
```

Comment: I had to modify create role as such:
`gcloud iam roles create role_test1 --project <project-name> --title "Role role_test1" --description "My custom role role_test1" --permissions bigquery.jobs.create,bigquery.jobs.get,bigquery.jobs.list,bigquery.jobs.listAll,bigquery.readsessions.create,bigquery.routines.get,bigquery.routines.list,bigquery.tables.export,bigquery.tables.getData,bigquery.tables.list,bigquery.transfers.get,resourcemanager.projects.get --stage GA`

Comment: It would be nice if the explanation above also removed dataset, table, and roles at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests on my end.

When an user has the 14 listed permissions, they are not even able to see the BigQuery Datasets on the UI. To do so, the `bigquery.datasets.get` permission must be added to the custom role.

Even with the 15 permissions, they are unable to Delete BigQuery tables so you are in the right path.

Being able to delete tables indicates that the user does not have the created Custom role assigned or has more permissions from additional roles. Please:

- Check that the Roles have been set correctly (my scenario with the 15 permissions). Be sure to save changes when assigning permissions to your Custom roles.

[image: Custom Role]

- In your [IAM Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/permissions/projectpermissions?_ga=2.198095151.1096816309.1582563226-2067321038.1564771749&_gac=1.2778756.1582327440.EAIaIQobChMI6ryunuTj5wIVEbvsCh1mZgYaEAAYASAAEgIH4PD_BwE) please double check that the user has this role linked to their account.
- Also check if the user does not have additional roles like Owner, Editor, BigQuery Admin, BigQuery Data Editor, etc. If they have any of those extra roles, their permissions are making them able to delete BigQuery tables.

[image: IAM Dashboard]

- Finally, double check who is logged into the UI, you can check it by clicking on the photo at the top right corner of your GCP UI. The user should not see an account different to `myUser@emaildomain.com` like in the following image

[image: GCP logged account]

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks so much for the extra effort.  We're trying this out now, will let everyone know the result.