# Prevent a user from deleting data from a BigQuery table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

I'm curious about is there a way to restrict a user the use of DELETE statement; I've read a less specific but similar doubt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326440/prevent-a-user-from-deleting-bigquery-tables) and consulted the related documentation [there](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-examples), besides swimming on [row-level security](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-row-level-security-with-features#legacy_sql), however the first two are focused on restrictions over deleting tables or datasets, and the third only works to let the user view rows under certain condition.

Do I have to define a condition on the IAM section, specifically for the user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In BigQuery, you can read or update the data. You can find the roles [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery).

Update means update the meta-data (the schema), update data, add data and.... `DELETE` data.

Therefore, you can only give a `READER` permission to BigQuery -> DataViewer role. If you allow to change the data, you *also* allow to delete the data.